# Issue with custom realloc function in c

Tags: c, shell

I wrote a simple implementation to `realloc()` that reallocates string pointers that need to be `tokenized`.

`realloc()` works fine with my `tokenizer()` on `valgrind` but i get the following errors on `p_reallocdp`,

```
==17128== Invalid read of size 8
==17128==    at 0x1095C5: p_reallocdp (c_stdlib.c:66)
==17128==    by 0x10AA88: tokenizer (tokenizer.c:36)
==17128==    by 0x10A3B5: shell_loop (shell_loop.c:23)
==17128==    by 0x10A16C: main (main.c:42)
==17128==  Address 0x4ad8fd0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==17128==    at 0x4841848: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:431)
==17128==    by 0x10954C: _reallocdp (c_stdlib.c:53)
==17128==    by 0x10A9EA: tokenizer (tokenizer.c:24)
==17128==    by 0x10A3B5: shell_loop (shell_loop.c:23)
==17128==    by 0x10A16C: main (main.c:42)
```

```
char **p_reallocdp(char **ptr, size_t dest)
{
    char **newptr; size_t i;
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return (malloc(sizeof(char *) * dest)); /* line 53 */

    newptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (dest));

    for (i = 0; i < dest; i++)
        newptr[i] = ptr[i]; /* line 66 */

    free(ptr);
    return (newptr);
}
```

tokenizer excerpt

```
char **tokens = NULL; char *token; size_t idx = 0;

    while (token)
    {
        tokens = p_reallocdp(tokens, ((idx + 1) * sizeof(char *))); /* line 24 */

        tokens[idx] = _strdup(token);

        idx++;
        token = _strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    tokens = p_reallocdp(tokens, ((idx + 1) * sizeof(char *))); /* line 36 */
```

Comment: so which line is `c_stdlib.c:66`? which line is `c_stdlib.c:53`? `= ptr[i];` does `ptr` point to valid memory of `dest` size? You would have to post a full-er [MCVE].

Comment: tried as much to follow mre. updated code with tokenzer and ptr points to a valid memory nulled on first attempt

Comment: That loop doesn't look right to me:  `for (i = 0; i < dest; i++ ) newptr[i] = ptr[i]; /* line 66 */`. `dest` is the new size so if the old size was smaller, the loop overflows
`

Comment: What is `CommandInfo`? Show how you call `tokenizer`. Read this very closely; [MRE], then [edit] apply what you've read.

Comment: you do not even check if malloc did not fail. Very poor code

Comment: A realloc function must know the previous size of the object.  When copying material from old to new, it must loop from 0 to min(old_size, new_size) because the loop accesses both the old and new object.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> tokens = p_reallocdp(tokens, ((idx + 1) * sizeof(char *)))
> ```
>
> ```
> for (i = 0; i < dest; i++)
>      newptr[i] = ptr[i]; /* line 66 */
> ```

There are no `dest` *elements* in `ptr`. There is the previous *count of elements* in `ptr` elements. And you have to copy previous *count of elements* from `ptr`, not the *future count of bytes* of elements from `ptr`.

In your code it looks like, `dest` represents the future the number of *bytes* the returned pointer will point to. There are no `dest` `char *` pointers in the memory, there are `dest` *bytes*. There will be `dest / sizeof(char*)` *elements*.

The way `realloc` works is that C standard library is internally keeping the size of allocated memory and can get the old size. The way `realloc` works, is that it copies *bytes* from one memory region to another, not `char *` elements.

You have to refactor your code to for example `p_reallocdp(char **, size_t oldcnt, size_t newcnt)` and call with `p_reallocdp(tokens, idx, idx + 1);` for example.

Or you could use a sentinel value of `NULL` in `char **tokens` array and get the previous count of elements in the array by traversing the  array until `NULL`.

Or you could refactor your code to a full OOP `struct tokens_s { char **tokens; size_t cnt; };` and do `int tokens_realloc(struct tokens_s *p, size_t newcnt);` and keep the old size with the toksn in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be reduced to:

```
char **p_reallocdp(char **ptr, size_t dest)
{
    return realloc(ptr, sizeof(*ptr) * (dest));
}
```

All your malloc magic is not needed as realloc does exactly what you want, more efficiently and without errors. Your code is very bad and invokes undefined behaviour when you copy pointers (as you access the `ptr` object outside its bounds) and potential UB if `malloc` fails (then you will dereference `NULL` pointer).